# Dynamic Subdomains - ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, coldfusion-11

Anyone know a way to create dynamic subdomains in coldfusion 11 without having to add them to a dns server?

I want to be able to redirect each of my clients in a personalized subdomain every time they log in to my system.

```
ex: client1.example.com client2.example.com
```

Comment: This may help. http://serverfault.com/questions/63200/how-do-i-create-subdomain-names-dynamically The logic is there but it'll be hard if you aren't running Apache.

Comment: Is your site in an IIS server?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan yes it is. I will try your solution below and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**This works if your site is hosted in a Windows IIS server.**

If you are using **IIS** then the following can help you. Use loops and conditions as your requirements.

```
<!--- Provide you IIS SiteName --->
<cfset siteName = "Your IIS Site Name">
<!--- Your new domain address --->
<cfset newSiteBinding = "client2.example.com">
<!--- your port address --->
<cfset newSitePort = 80>
<cfset fileID = createUUID()>
<cfsavecontent variable="ex"><cfoutput>cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD set site /site.name: #siteName# /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:#newSitePort#:#newSiteBinding#']</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cffile  action = "write"
    file = "E:\#fileID#.bat"
    output = "#ex#"
/>

<cfexecute  name="E:\#fileID#.bat"
    arguments="/c set"
    variable="data"
    timeout="10" 
/>

<cffile  action = "delete"
    file = "E:\#fileID#.bat"
>
```

What we are basically doing is that we are creating a `.bat` file and executing it using [`cfexecute`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfexecute). Please note that you need to be careful with the paths because the Directory structure might be different in your server.

**.BAT file content Example**

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD set site /site.name: example /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='client2.example.com:80:*']
```

[How the command works](http://tech.avivo.si/tag/adding-binding-to-iis-from-command-line/). Notice the `+` at `/+bindings`?

That means adding a new binding and `/-bindings` tries to remove an existing binding.

Comment: So this is creating bindings for each of my users if I understand it correctly? What is the difference if I just add the usernames manually as bindings on IIS?

Comment: @Geo I am not sure. I don't think there is anything to do with users in the case of IIS website bindings. Only thing necessary is that coldfusion have administrative privileges for the command to be executed.